# How do you bind menu items to a ContextMenu in silverlight, including the icon

Tags: silverlight, xaml, icons, contextmenu, itemssource

I have a context menu and i want its menu items populated via a binding.
The following code works

```
<Button>
    <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu>
    </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

but there's one problem, the ItemTemplate represents the Text area of a menu item and so as far as im aware doesnt allow you to set the icon

so i tried doing the binding via the ItemContainerStyle as in the below example

```
<Button>
    <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Style>
            </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu>
    </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

but silverlight doesnt seem to like that

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I create a context menu [programmatically](http://vikingerik.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/silverlight4-copypaste-context-menu/) and setting the content to the MenuItem.Header property seems to work just fine for images. There are a [lot](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=512&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) of [examples](http://www.dansoltesz.com/post/2010/05/27/Silverlight-4-textbox-right-click-context-menu-with-cut-copy-and-paste-behavior.aspx) of setting text.

Comment: Creating the menu programatically would work but it breaks my mvvm pattern, thats why im looking for some way to do it with binding alone

Answer (score 0):

Try using this open source menu instead:

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com

The template allows binding of images directly.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question, and though I did not find the answer I wanted, I found a workaround that met my needs nicely. I thought you might like to see it, even this long after-the-fact.

It appears that if the `ItemsSource` of the `ContextMenu` class contains `MenuItem` objects, then the icon lands nicely where it belongs. I, like you, was using a view model and didn't what to inject UI logic into my view model class.

What I did instead was implement a value converter to transform my view model into `MenuItem` objects. It looked a little something like this:

---

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DelegatedValueConverter
        x:Key="LocalContextItemConverter"
        Converting="OnBindingContextMenu" />
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<toolkit:ContextMenu
    ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems, Converter={StaticResource LocalContextItemConverter}}" />
```

---

**C# Code-Behind**

```
private void OnBindingContextMenu(object sender, ValueConvertingEventArgs e)
{
    var dataitems = e.Value as IEnumerable< NavigationItemViewModel >;
    if (dataitems != null)
    {
        var items = dataitems.Select(data => new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = data.Title,
            Icon = data.Icon,
            Tag = data
        }).ToList();
        var handler = new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnContextMenuClick);
        items.ForEach(item => item.Click += handler);
        e.Result = items
    }
}

private void OnContextMenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

---

**Discussion**

The `DelegatedValueConverter` is a little something I describe in detail [here](http://www.notesoncode.com/articles/2011/03/05/AOneSizeFitsAllIValueConverterImplementation.aspx), but it is not really important. You could roll your own value converter and use it instead.

The `Title` property of my view model is a string, and `Icon` is an instance of `Image`. I use the `Tag` property of the menu item to keep a reference to my view model so that I can refer to the non-visual data in it during a click event.

This solution is convenient because it still provides some separation between the UI and the view model, though I would prefer in this case a purely-declarative solution.

I hope this helps!